# Windows 10 running games slowly

Tags: window, directx, windows-10-preview

**Issue: All my games running on Windows 10 are running slowly**

When I tried Unturned on my Windows 7, I get around 50~60 FPS

But when I played the game on Windows 10 Insider Program, I get much lower FPS

> **Unturned running on Windows 10. Notice the FPS on the Top-Right is only 8FPS**[image]

At first, I thought it was just Unturned, but it affect ALL my games. These include:

- **Unturned**
- **Middle Earth: Shadow of Mordor**
- **XCOM: Enemy Unknown**
- **PayDay**

I do understand this is a beta version of Windows, but I can't see any info regarding this slowdown either on Google or by Microsoft themselves

**Info:**
*OS: Windows 10 Technical Preview: Build 9841*
*CPU: Intel i5 3rd Generation (Unsure exact model)*
*GPU: Intel HD 4000*
*RAM: 4GB RAM*
*Resolution: 1366x768 Native*

Comment: do you have graphic drivers created for windows 10?

Comment: Normal ones (drivers) seem to work fine...? (I have mine running the same setup as him, and I haven't been getting any performance loss)

Comment: Yes, I have some friends who are also running Windows 10 developers preview, yet have no apparent performance issues.

Comment: If you have a way to compare apples and apples, then check to see if the exact same drivers are being used, and the "Settings" a tiny change in the AA or AF tessellation settings, could make a world of difference in the visual and frame rate.  Also the V-sync being on, could effect frame rate. Any even minor difference in hardware or cooling could make a world of difference

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an un-finished operating system that isn't even in Beta yet and there's no point in supporting/helping because the OS will change a lot before it's finally released.

Comment: [Cross Network Duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189535/windows-10-running-games-slowly)

Comment: @Psycogeek. For the game, all settings are at the lowest and that Resoultion was set to 50%. We both use the same computer (exactly) so it cannot be a hardware problem. We both are using the same build (9841)

Comment: How are the temperatures (on either) when running? And what is the clock rate? Intel will do a great job of throttling, and many motherboards have capability to do huge adjustments of clock rate, bus rate , and something as simple as the cache clock rate can vary processing speed. The amount of shared memory for the gpu on-die (in uefi or bios) Total memory installed, and timings (rate) it works at.  Are any background tasks being processed in the OS itself? scheduled tasks running? Different programs installed even, some programs will be doing  tasks? FPS log and testing overlays slow things.

Comment: Its fine @Psycogeek :). I have resorted to replace Windows 10 with my older build of Windows 8, and everything seems to work fine again. Still wondering why it only affect my build, and not my friends, even though we have the SAME PC, with the SAME HARDWARE, and the SAME PROGRAMS?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 is only available as a *technical preview* at this point.  It is not even a release candidate.  There are likely all sorts of performance optimizations that have been left disabled, debug logging left enabled, and limited driver support - all of which are going to cause system performance to not be at their finest.  Microsoft is still working on the feature capabilities at this point, and will still require some time to work on performance.

Good luck finding Windows 10 video drivers at this point, which would be a first step in maybe helping to resolve some of what you're seeing.